# 今からTensorflowを勉強するのに、適正なバージョンはいくつですか？

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

Tensorflowで機械学習の勉強を始めたばかりのものです。

いくつかのサイトに目を通していると、Tensorflowのバージョン違いによるトラブルなどが数多いようです。また勉強するのにもバージョン2以上はまだ情報が少ないので学習には適さないとの話もありました。

今からTensorflowを勉強するのに、スタート地点として適正なTensorflowバージョンはいくつですか？

Windows7 64bit
Anaconda3

Answer (score 1):

学習教材にあわせたバージョンが良いです。
初学者であればセットアップでつまずいたりしないように、バージョンが明記されていない教材は避けましょう。

機械学習のライブラリはまだ枯れておらず積極的に開発が進んでいます。
例えメジャーバージョンが同じであっても関数名や引数が変わることがありますので、可能な限りマイナーバージョンまで同じものを使用することをお勧めします。
教材と異なるバージョンを使うとコピペしたコードでコンパイルエラーが出たり意図した結果が出なかったりしてハマることがあります。

なおOSまで同じものを使うのは確かに正しい姿勢かもしれませんが、サポートの切れたOSを用いるよりは教材を新しいものに変える方が良いかもしれません。